# On click open another div with same data-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below, you can see that I have `div` class `card bg-dark text-white` with `data-index` 0, 1, 2. After that I have another `div` elements, with class `over-menu active` and their `data-index` 0, 1, 2.

I have not tried anything so far because I do not how to do it.

```
 <div class="card bg-dark text-white" data-index="0">
 <div class="card bg-dark text-white" data-index="1">
 <div class="card bg-dark text-white" data-index="2">

<div class="over-menu active" data-index="0">
<div class="over-menu active" data-index="1">
<div class="over-menu active" data-index="2">
```

What I want to achieve is the next: When I click on a `div` class `card bg-dark text-white` with `data-index` 0 to open me the `div` class `over-menu active` with `data-index` 0, same for when `data-index` is 1, 2,...

Below is the code, can you please tell me how can I achieve that.

Comment: You've tagged the question with jQuery, why not look up how to create a click event handler in jQuery?  In that handler you need information from the element being clicked, then you look up how to read a `data-*` attribute in jQuery.  And so on.

Comment: @David wagt do you mean? How can I achieve that with an event handler?

Comment: Honestly, start with the basics.  There are *countless* examples on the internet of how to create a click handler with jQuery.  Start there.  Maybe walk through some introductory tutorials on jQuery.  Make the effort to learn the basics.  We can help if you encounter a specific problem, but simply not being familiar with the technologies you want to use isn't really a specific problem.  Tutorials exist for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `card` `div` is clicked, you can find the data value from the clicked div, and then iterate over `over-menu` divs to find the `div` with corresponding data value:

```
$('.card').click(function(){
  var _val = $(this).data('index');
  $('.over-menu').each(function(){
     if (_val === $(this).data('index')){
       //do something
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With pure **JavaScript**, you can get all the elements with its **`data-index`** attribute by using [**`Document.querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
.

**Example:**

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("div[data-index]");
```

You can get a specific element by using [**`Document.querySelector()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

**Example:**

```
var target = document.querySelector("div[data-index=\"" + index + "\"].over-menu");
```

You can get the current value of the **`data-index`** attribute with [**`HTMLElement.dataset`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

**Example:**

```
var index = element.target.dataset.index;
```

Something like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  (function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll("div[data-index]"), len = elems.length, div;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      div = elems[i];
      div.onclick = clickAction;
    }

    function clickAction(e) {
      var index = e.target.dataset.index, target = document.querySelector("div[data-index=\"" + index + "\"].over-menu");
      resetSelectedElements();
      target.classList.add("selected");
    }

    function resetSelectedElements() {
      var targetElements = document.getElementsByClassName("over-menu"), len = targetElements.length, targetElement;

      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        targetElement = targetElements[i];
        targetElement.classList.remove("selected");
      }
    }
  }());
};
```

```css
.card.bg-dark.text-white,
.over-menu.active {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.card.bg-dark.text-white {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.over-menu.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: inherit;
  display: none;
}

.over-menu.active.selected {
  border: #0a0 solid 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card bg-dark text-white" data-index="0">Index: 0</div>
<div class="card bg-dark text-white" data-index="1">Index: 1</div>
<div class="card bg-dark text-white" data-index="2">Index: 2</div>
<hr />
<div class="over-menu active" data-index="0">Index: 0</div>
<div class="over-menu active" data-index="1">Index: 1</div>
<div class="over-menu active" data-index="2">Index: 2</div>
```

In this demo I have a CSS style to show the proper `div` when its selected.

```
.over-menu.active.selected {
  border: #0A0 solid 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: How do I call the function to work on click on the card div in the js?

Comment: @ViktorGavrilovic In my answer I'm using: `div.onclick = clickAction;` to show the `div`.

Comment: I have tried your code on a whole new code and it is working perfectly, but I have no idea why when I implement in my code is not working properly

Comment: @ViktorGavrilovic I've updated my answer. Let me know if this works properly in your code page. Try to see Chrome Developer Tools in order to find errors.

Answer (score 0):

You  could do something like

```
$('.card bg-dark.text-white').click (function (){
  var elem = $('.over-menu.active').find($(this).data('index'));
 // do what you need with elem
 });
```

Comment: Will this work as I mentioned before? When i c”ick on the div card with data-index 0 to open the div open-menu.active with data-index 0?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .over-menu , .active{
            display: none;
        }
        .card{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card bg-dark text-white" data-index="0" onclick="fun1();">click me 1</div>
    <div class="card bg-dark text-white" data-index="1" onclick="fun2();">click me 2</div>
    <div class="card bg-dark text-white" data-index="2" onclick="fun3();">click me 3</div>

    <div class="over-menu active" data-index="0" id="1">1</div>
    <div class="over-menu active" data-index="1" id="2">2</div>
    <div class="over-menu active" data-index="2" id="3">3</div>
    <script>
        function fun1() {
            document.getElementById("1").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("2").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("3").style.display = "none";
        }
        function fun2() {
            document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("2").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("3").style.display = "none";
        }
        function fun3() {
            document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("2").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("3").style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below acts as you want, the `CSS` is all optional, with the exception of the following lines:

```
.over-menu {
  display: none;
}

.over-menu.selected {
  display: inherit;
}
```

All the other CSS is just to aid the user experience in the demo.

I've commented each line of the code to explain what is going on.

Let me know if you needed anything else.

```js
// Add click event to all cards
$(".card").click( function() {

  // Remove previous selection
  $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
  
  // Get data-index from clicked .card
  var dataIndex = $(this).attr("data-index");
  
  // Add selected class to corresponding over-menu
  $(".over-menu[data-index=" + dataIndex + "]").addClass("selected");
  
  // Add selected class to the card 
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  
});
```

```css
.card, .over-menu {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.card.selected {
  background: blue;
}

.over-menu {
  display: none;
}

.over-menu.selected {
  display: inherit;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Card components:</label>

<div class="full-width">
  <div class="card bg-dark text-white" data-index="0">0</div>
  <div class="card bg-dark text-white" data-index="1">1</div>
  <div class="card bg-dark text-white" data-index="2">2</div>
</div>

<hr>

<label>Over-menu components:</label>
<div class="full-width">
  <div class="over-menu active" data-index="0">0</div>
  <div class="over-menu active" data-index="1">1</div>
  <div class="over-menu active" data-index="2">2</div>
</div>
```